# Hacer suma de un distinct del campo entidad sql

Tags: sql

```
select distinct entidad, sum(cast(num_importe as float))
from envio_remesa
inner join remesa 
on envio_remesa.id = remesa.envio_remesa_id 
where remesa.envio_remesa_id = 3 and remesa.tipo_doc='201';
```

El caso es que por ejemplo tengo dos entidades distintas (supongamos 18 y 21,pero puede ser cualquier número), y quiero agrupar en dos registros distintos la **suma** del **num_importe** para la entidad 18, y la **suma** del **num_importe** para la entidad 21. ¿Estoy cerca? ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Lo que quiero que salga:

```
entidad   num_importe

18        92.300,00

21        56.000,20

432       120.000,32

12        12.232,12
```

Comment: Si estas muy cerca, tanto como quitar el `DISTINCT` y agregar al final `GROUP BY entidad`

Comment: Concuerdo con lo que dice @PatricioMoracho. Para que comprendas mejor, el distinct te sirve para que no se tomen valores repetidos, en este caso de tu campo entidad. Pero la suma agrupada que requieres debes hacerla con el GROUP BY. Ya que la suma que harías es sumar el num_importe de todas las entidades iguales.